# How do I use ASM to spoof a HelloWorld.scala? Loaded to JVM but not found?

Tags: java, scala, classloader, java-bytecode-asm

I've used ASM with java using a custom classloader, but I'm having trouble doing the same in scala.  What's the preferred approach?

A `HelloScala.scala` compiles into *two* classes (`HelloScala.class` *and* `HelloScala$.class`).  Do I need to spoof the bytecode for both?

My code appears to be stuffed in just one, `HelloScala$.class`, but there is no public constructor or methods.  I can use the Reflection API and use Constructor to get access, but two issues:

1. By ignoring the `HelloScala.class`, am I missing anything valuable?
2. Is this dangerous or smelly?

The "right" way is probably to invoke the public, static `main` in `HelloScala`, but I get this error:

```
[Loaded HelloScala from __JVM_DefineClass__]
[Loaded scala.ScalaObject from file:/home/julianpeeters/asm-scala-example/lib/scala-library-2.9.1.jar]
[Loaded HelloScala$ from __JVM_DefineClass__]
[Loaded sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl from /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl from /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException from /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/rt.jar]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at HelloScalaDump.main(HelloScalaDump.java:41)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloScala$
    at HelloScala.main(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloScala$
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:373)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 6 more
```

It appears that `HelloScala$` is getting loaded, so why can't it be found?

Thanks!

Comment: _"Supposedly, you don't want to have multiple useless files in your project dir..."_ -- No, I don't mind multiple files. My problem is actually that I don't have _any_ .java or .class files that represent these classes, so there is nothing to put in a jar.  Instead, I'm trying to define the classes dynamically at runtime (based on data only known at runtime).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, calling the `dump()` method in each class' 'dump' file to load the classes with the context's ClassLoader and not a custom classloader (so the spoofed classes have access to the same classpath as the rest of the project):

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class DumpLoader {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     Class<?> c$ = loadClass("HelloScala$", HelloScala$Dump.dump()); //First load the "anonymous" class
     Class<?> c = loadClass("HelloScala", HelloScalaDump.dump());   //Then load the "real" class
     try {
       Method mainMethod = c.getMethod("main", String[].class);  //Get the main method of the "real" class
       mainMethod.invoke(null, (Object) new String[]{});        //and invoke it to run the spoofed program
     } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
     }
  }

  private static Class loadClass(String className, byte[] b) {
    //override classDefine (as it is protected) and define the class.
    Class<?> clazz = null;
    try {
     // ClassLoader loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
      ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
      Class<?> cls = Class.forName("java.lang.ClassLoader");
      Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("defineClass", new Class[] { String.class, byte[].class, int.class, int.class });

      // protected method invocaton
      method.setAccessible(true);
      try {
        Object[] args = new Object[] { className, b, new Integer(0), new Integer(b.length)};
        clazz = (Class) method.invoke(loader, args);
      } finally {
        method.setAccessible(false);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
    return clazz;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Scala uses a lot of tricks to map it's semantics to the JVM. You'll therefore see a lot of unexpected things at the bytecode level. I think you'll have to take it and dive into how the scala compiler uses the Java Structures.

A class is identified by it's name and the class loader which loaded the class (the one that called the define method). Are you sure the loader which loaded HelloScala actually loaded HelloScala$ as well?

Comment: _"Are you sure the loader which loaded HelloScala actually loaded HelloScala$ as well?"_

Comment: _"Are you sure the loader which loaded HelloScala actually loaded HelloScala$ as well?"_  -- I've got two different instances of a DynamicClassLoader class.  Both classes appear to be loaded (see the first 3 lines of the error message in the answer). Do the classes need to be loaded by the same instance?

Comment: Loading both classes with the same instance of the `DynamicClassLoader` worked, up to a point... then `scalaObject` couldn't be found from `scala-library` and I realized that I couldn't extend, I'd have to get and override the methods of the ContextClassLoader.  Thanks for keeping me pointed in the right direction.